# different strategies for finding Quartile in excel

Tags: excel, statistics, quartile

let us consider following data

```
9
5
3
10
14
6
12
7
14
```

i would like to find  `Q1,Q2,Q3,let sort  data

```
3
5
6
7
9
10
12
14
14
```

in excel  we can calculate it  very easily

```
=QUARTILE(A2:A10,1)

=QUARTILE(A2:A10,2)

=QUARTILE(B2:B10,3)
```

results are

```
6
9
12
```

but if we calculate by hand, we will get following results

```
5.5
9
13
```

why is result  so different?thanks in advance

Comment: See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/QUARTILE-function-93cf8f62-60cd-4fdb-8a92-8451041e1a2a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US. Use `QUARTILE.EXC` to get your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of Quartile is not unequivocally. So there are multiple methods to calculate the Quartile. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile

In Excel there are multiple Quartile functions now, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/QUARTILE-function-93cf8f62-60cd-4fdb-8a92-8451041e1a2a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

`QUARTILE` and `QUARTILE.INC` uses Method 2 while `QUARTILE.EXC` uses Method 1.